# Can I create custom paths for lead or opportunity number/conversions according to lead source?

Tags: opportunity, lead-conversion, sales-cloud, salespath

I wanted to create a guided path in sales cloud for leads & opportunity. This path should be different for leads/opportunities from a different source.

For example - I want to create a separate call center script for leads created through the website (lead form) and a separate script for leads created through inbound calls.

Currently, I am able to create only one path on an object (lead or opportunity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using out-of-the-box functionality; you'd need to write a custom component to do that.

Out of the box, you get [one Path per object per record type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=path_overview.htm).

> You can set up one path for each available record type. Steps for each path (1) are based on values in the picklist that you select when you set up the path.

If you chose to set up your org to have a Record Type for each Lead Source, you'd make this possible, but that would come with a lot of maintenance and customization overhead that you may not want. However, if your Lead Sources are few and have well-defined, distinct processes associated with them, you may want a Record Type for each anyway - allowing you to use distinct page layouts for each one.